# ¿Como capturo una variable de un href en thymeleaf Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

resulta que al ejecutar mi aplicacion spring boot no captura la variable, y me muestra un error 404:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

**Código:**

```
 @RequestMapping( value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteAll(@PathVariable("id") int va){
        System.out.println(va);
        return "redirect:/show";
    }
```

**html con thymeleaf:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <th>
        <tr>
            <td>Order id</td>
            <td>Customer id</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Action</td>
         </tr>
     </th>
     <th:block th:each="list : ${lists}">
         <tr>
            <td th:text="${list.orderId}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${list.customer.name}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${list.product}">...</td>
            <td>

                <a th:href="@{/delete/(id=${list.orderId})}">Delete</a>...
            </td>
         </tr>
      </th:block> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba concatenando el th:href de la siguiente manera:

```
th:href="@{/delete/} + ${list.orderId}"
```